# Is there an R function to enumerate variations?

Tags: r, combinatorics

I would like to find k-element **variations** of n elements with repetition not allowed as defined in [this](https://webpages.charlotte.edu/ghetyei/courses/old/S19.3166/pcv.pdf) document. I found several posts considering combinations and permutations but non dealing with variations. From the cited document, "variations are arrangements of selections of objects, where the order of the selected objects matters." I cannot find suitable function in the `combinat` package. I want to achieve result equivalent to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17683955/5423259) answer but for variations, not combinations.

An example:
We have n=4 elements and want to find the k=2 element variations. There should be 12 possible variations:

1 and 2; 1 and 3; 1 and 4;

2 and 1; 2 and 3; 2 and 4;

3 and 1; 3 and 2; 3 and 4;

4 and 1; 4 and 2; 4 and 3.

Comment: Unless I’m overlooking something this is equivalent to the combinations of n, take m elements both forward and backwards. For your example: `cbind(combn(1 : 4, 2L), combn(4 : 1, 2L))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problably you can use `expand.grid` and then filter out the rows with duplicates

```
n <- 4
k <- 2
d <- expand.grid(rep(list(seq(n)), k))
d[apply(d, 1, anyDuplicated) == 0, ]
```

which gives

```
   Var1 Var2
2     2    1
3     3    1
4     4    1
5     1    2
7     3    2
8     4    2
9     1    3
10    2    3
12    4    3
13    1    4
14    2    4
15    3    4
```

---

If you want more programming exercises, you can try coding with your own function

```
n <- 4
k <- 2

f <- function(n, k) {
  if (k == 1) {
    return(1:n)
  }
  r <- c()
  for (l in Recall(n, k - 1)) {
    v <- 1:n
    u <- v[!v %in% l]
    r <- c(r, Map(c, list(l), u))
  }
  r
}
```

which gives

```
> f(n, k)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 3

[[3]]
[1] 1 4

[[4]]
[1] 2 1

[[5]]
[1] 2 3

[[6]]
[1] 2 4

[[7]]
[1] 3 1

[[8]]
[1] 3 2

[[9]]
[1] 3 4

[[10]]
[1] 4 1

[[11]]
[1] 4 2

[[12]]
[1] 4 3
```