# How to calculate powerset a set s={1,2,3,....,2000}

Tags: r

When I calculate a powerset using

```
 powerset = function(s){

    len = length(s)
    l = vector(mode="list",length=2^len) ; l[[1]]=numeric()
    counter = 1L
    for(x in 1L:length(s)){
        for(subset in 1L:length(s)){
            counter=counter+1L
            l[[counter]] = c(l[[x]],s[subset])
        }
    }
    return(l)
}

s<-1:2000
powerset(s)
```

I'm getting the following error

> Error in vector(mode = "list", length = 2^len) :    vector size cannot
>   be infinite

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If a previous question gets closed (like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546212/calculate-power-set-for-a-big-vector-22000-more-efficiently), it usually is better to improve the existing question rather than ask a nearly identical one.

Comment: Also, there are about `10 ^ 80` atoms in the universe (http://www.universetoday.com/36302/atoms-in-the-universe/), which is approximately `2 ^ 265`.  So `2 ^ 2000` is bigger than you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2^2000=1.148e+602
It is too long that r can not generate it.
I suggest you use the database to deal with it.

Comment: How do you know that number is too large? Can you provide a reference? Also: how would the solution look like if one were to use the database?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because:

```
> 2^1024
[1] Inf
> 2^1023
[1] 8.988466e+307
> .Machine$double.xmax
[1] 1.797693e+308
```

Comment: how i calculat this set powerset?

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the powerset, use [`set_power`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sets/docs/set_power) in `sets`.  (Or possibly [`cset_power`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sets/docs/cset_power) or [`gset_power`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sets/docs/gset_power), if you need the additional functionality offered by those set types.)

```
library(sets)
set_power(1:5)
## {{}, {1L}, {2L}, {3L}, {4L}, {5L}, {1L, 2L}, {1L, 3L}, {1L, 4L}, {1L, 5L}, {2L, 3L}, {2L, 4L}, {2L, 5L}, {3L, 4L}, {3L, 5L},
##  {4L, 5L}, {1L, 2L, 3L}, {1L, 2L, 4L}, {1L, 2L, 5L}, {1L, 3L, 4L}, {1L, 3L, 5L}, {1L, 4L, 5L}, {2L, 3L, 4L}, {2L, 3L, 5L},
##  {2L, 4L, 5L}, {3L, 4L, 5L}, {1L, 2L, 3L, 4L}, {1L, 2L, 3L, 5L}, {1L, 2L, 4L, 5L}, {1L, 3L, 4L, 5L}, {2L, 3L, 4L, 5L}, {1L,
##  2L, 3L, 4L, 5L}}
```

As noted by Colonel Beauvel however, for a set with 2000 elements, the powerset will be `2 ^ 2000` elements, which is too big for R to cope with.  R can, in theory, create vectors up to [`2 ^ 52`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/LongVectors) elements long, assuming that you have enough memory, though (as of 2014) you're likely to run out of RAM with vectors of `2 ^ 30something`.

Comment: actually speaking about the .machine$integer.max is more relevant since @Saeed used vector length in his code!

Answer (score 0):

I´ve been using the ggm package powerset function to powerset a list of variable names. For what I have experienced with that function, the maximum length you can use is 22 elements. Larger than that, R returns that it is too long.

My suggestion is to limit the length of your subsets. You could use (for subsets of max length K):

```
subsets <- do.call("c", lapply(0:K, combn, x = your list, simplify = FALSE))
```

For more, read: 
[How to compute all power sets with cardinality at most K?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53490809/how-to-compute-all-power-sets-with-cardinality-at-most-k)