# Create all dataset combinations from a data frame in R

Tags: r

I need help to develop a code to create all dataset combinations from a data frame in R.

E.g.
dataframe =

```
        | A  B  C |
        | 1  4  7 |
        | 2  5  8 |
        | 3  6  9 |
```

Dataset combinations: A, B, C, AB, AC, BC, ABC

data1 =

```
    | A |
    | 1 |
    | 2 |
    | 3 |
```

data2 =

```
    | B |
    | 4 |
    | 5 |
    | 6 |
```

data3 =

```
    | C |
    | 7 |
    | 8 |
    | 9 |
```

data4 =

```
    | A  B | 
    | 1  4 |
    | 2  5 |
    | 3  6 |
```

data5 =

```
    | A  C |
    | 1  7 |
    | 2  8 |
    | 3  9 |
```

data6 =

```
    | B  C |
    | 4  7 |
    | 5  8 |
    | 6  9 |
```

data7 = | A

```
    | A  B  C |
    | 1  4  7 |
    | 2  5  8 |
    | 3  6  9 |
```

Kind regards.

Comment: This is called the power set in mathematics. Here is a [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715580/algorithm-to-calculate-power-set-all-possible-subsets-of-a-set-in-r). To make this work for your example, use the resulting sets to select subsets of the data frame in a loop or `lapply`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `lapply` and `combn` (to get variable name combinations)

```
colNameSet <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(length(df)),
                           function(i) combn(names(df), i, simplify=FALSE)), recursive=FALSE)

myList <- lapply(colNameSet, function(x) df[x])
```

The vector of 1...k where k is the number of variables is fed to `lapply` which tells `combn` the size of variable combinations to make in each iteration. The result of each `combn` call is a list because of the simplify=FALSE statement. Thus the result of `lapply` is a nested list. `unlist` with recursive=FALSE flattens the list.

The second line runs through this list of variable names and subsets the data frame based on the contents of each element.

Which returns

```
 myList
[[1]]
  A
1 1
2 2
3 3

[[2]]
  B
1 4
2 5
3 6
...

[[6]]
  B C
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9

[[7]]
  A B C
1 1 4 7
2 2 5 8
3 3 6 9
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:9, 3))
names(df) <- LETTERS[1:3]
```